# QProcess in thread works but with two type output errors

Tags: multithreading, qt, qprocess

I'am learning QT multithreading.
With the following code, it works ok, but there are two type errors
The code is too simple to figure out what's going wrong.

CmdController(Controller thread) -> CMD(Ping test thread) -> QProcess(excute "ping")

main.c

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        // create Test object, and then execute “ping” cmd under windows
        CmdController Test;
        Test.process();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

CmdController.h

```
    // deal with "ping" command
    class Cmd : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Cmd();

    private:
        QProcess CmdExe;

    public slots:
        void process();
        void readFromStdOut();
    };


    // Controller class
    class CmdController : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit CmdController();
        ~CmdController();

    signals:
        void process();

    private:
        QThread mThread;
        Cmd mCmd;
    };
```

CmdController.c

```
    Cmd::Cmd()
    {
        connect(&CmdExe, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readFromStdOut()));
    }

    void Cmd::process()
    {
        CmdExe.start("ping", {"www.baidu.com"});
    }


    void Cmd::readFromStdOut()
    {
        QByteArray resault = CmdExe.readAllStandardOutput();
        qDebug() << QTextCodec::codecForName("GBK")->toUnicode(resault);
    }

    CmdController::CmdController()
    {
        mCmd.moveToThread(&mThread);
        connect(this, &CmdController::process, &mCmd, &Cmd::process);

        mThread.start();
    }

    CmdController::~CmdController()
    {
        mThread.exit();
        mThread.wait();
    }
```

The output:

```
    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
    (Parent is QProcess(0x6ffdf0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1f6510), current thread is QThread(0x6ffdd0)
    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
    (Parent is QProcess(0x6ffdf0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1f6510), current thread is QThread(0x6ffdd0)
    QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
    (Parent is QProcess(0x6ffdf0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1f6510), current thread is QThread(0x6ffdd0)
    "\r\n正在 Ping www.a.shifen.com [180.101.49.42] 具有 32 字节的数据:\r\n"
    "来自 180.101.49.42 的回复: 字节=32 时间=31ms TTL=53\r\n"
    "来自 180.101.49.42 的回复: 字节=32 时间=31ms TTL=53\r\n"
    "来自 180.101.49.42 的回复: 字节=32 时间=30ms TTL=53\r\n"
    "来自 180.101.49.42 的回复: 字节=32 时间=30ms TTL=53\r\n\r\n180.101.49.42 的 Ping 统计信息:\r\n    数据包: 已发送 = 4，已接收 = 4，丢失 = 0 (0% 丢失)，\r\n往返行程的估计时间(以毫秒为单位):\r\n    最短 = 30ms，最长 = 31ms，平均 = 30ms\r\n"
    QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'HANDLE'
    (Make sure 'HANDLE' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Error 1st:
1-6 lines output error, shows creating children object fails, by three times.
The ping test is ok.
so, who cause the error?

QThread(0x6ffdd0) is Cmd-object,
QThread(0x1f6510) is CmdController-object,
QProcess(0x6ffdf0) clearly is QProcess-object,
does it mean the QProcess, try to create something?

Error 2ed:
last two lines.
googled, cann't find 'HANDLE' what it is.

If if remove multithreading stuff from
CmdController(Controller thread) -> CMD(Ping test thread) -> QProcess(excute "ping")
to
CmdController(Controller thread) -> QProcess(excute "ping")
there will be no error, everything works perfectly.

I'am confused.

Thank you.

Comment: This is why low-level threading is not recommended in c++

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem, one must first be clear that a QObject must be executed only in the thread to which it belongs, if another thread is executed then Qt does not guarantee that it works, and that is what has happened in this case.

Let's analyze to which thread each QObject belongs, by default QObject belongs to the thread where it was created or to the thread of its father, so when you create the object "Test" this belongs the main thread, the object "mCmd" at the beginning belongs to the main thread and then you move it to "mThread", "CmdExe" belongs to the thread where it was created, that is to say to the main thread but the "Cmd" process method is executed in the secondary thread but "CmdExe" is executed in the main thread causing the problem.

The solution is to make "CmdExe" the son of "Cmd" so that both belong to the same thread and not generate problems.

```
// ...
class Cmd : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Cmd(QObject *parent=nullptr);

private:
    QProcess *CmdExe;
public slots:
    void process();
    void readFromStdOut();
};
// ...
```

```
// ...
Cmd::Cmd(QObject *parent):QObject(parent), CmdExe(new QProcess(this))
{
    connect(CmdExe, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &Cmd::readFromStdOut);
}

void Cmd::process()
{
    CmdExe->start("ping", {"www.baidu.com"});
}
// ...
```